# HTML input image button tag tag not recognised in Firefox and Edge browsers

Tags: php, html

I have this HTML button code at the end of a form
:

```
input type="image" name="enter" value ="test" src = "design_files/addpanier.png
```

It generates the button and I can click on it, but when I test for the button in PHP using:

```
if(isset($_POST['enter'])).....
```

it is not detected in Firefox or Mircosoft Edge but is OK in Chrome.

I have got round it by duplicating the 'enter' field using a hidden field

i.e.

```
input type="hidden" name="enter" value= "enter" 

input type="image" name="enter" value ="test" src = "design_files/addpanier.png"
```

The values in the field don't matter.

But is my original code wrong or are the browsers at fault?

Comment: Should we assume you have a correctly formatted HTML input tag i.e. `<input ....... >` Or is your code as you have actually posted it?

Comment: Waited 30 minutes for a reply? Guess it is just a typo then

Answer (score 0):

You need to test for the presence of an `enter.x` (or `enter.y`), instead of `enter`, in the form data. The reason is that for an image submit button, the contribution to the form data is defined differently from other fields: the coordinates of the clicked location (or 0, 0 if a method other than a pointing device was used) are included in the data, with names derived from the `name` attribute value with the strings `.x` and `.y` appended. (Some browsers also include a field with the name from the `name` attribute, but this isn’t useful since you cannot count on it.)

Ref.: [Description of input type=image at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image) (Follow the links to specs to find the most authoritative definitions of what happens at form submission.)